# JQuery - Increment counter in div tag only if two consecutive polls do not have the same status

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

I have a poller running in my Javascript, which calls a PHP file every 30 seconds.

The PHP file returns one of the following JSON in each interval. Sometimes, it could return the same JSON with same "status".

```
ex: 
    {"message":"Action","status":"pending"}
    {"message":"Update","status":"requested"}
    {"message":"Request","status":"processing"}
    {"message":"Delete","status":"completed"}
```

If the data in the status field received in two consecutive polls is not the same, I need to update a counter in a DIV (like your notification bubble)

Consider this application flow:

```
        1. When page loads, the counter in div tag is empty. 
             a. Poller runs the first time after 30 seconds.
             b. Poller receives pending status.
             c. Increment the counter in div tag.

        2. The counter in div tag is 1 now.
            a. Poller runs the second time after 30 seconds.
            b. Poller receives "requested" status.
            c. Increment the counter in div tag because the status received now is 
               different than what was received in the previous request.

        3. The counter in div tag is 2 now.
            a. Poller runs the third time.
            b. Poller receives the same "requested" status.
            c. DO NOT Increment the counter, because the status received 
               in #2 is the same as in #3.
```

How do I do this?

This is what I have so far in my OO JS:

```
    var Poller = {

        //This function runs as as poller every 30 seconds.
        monitorStatus: function()
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/getStatus.php",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data)
                {
                    if(data == null)
                    {
                      return false;
                    }
                var status = data.status;
                if(typeof status !== "undefined")
                {
                    if(status != "")
                    {
                        Poller.updateDivCounter(status.toLowerCase(), data.message);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    },

    updateDivCounter: function(status, message)
    {
        //ADD CODE TO MAKE SURE WE UPDATE THE COUNTER ONLY IF THE STATUS IN TWO 
          CONSECUTIVE POLLS IS NOT THE SAME.
        //......Need help

        //Increment the notificationCount DIV Tag
        $(".notificationCount").text( function (i,current) { return +current+1;} ) ;

        //Print the notification in notificationMessage Div tag
        $(".notificationMessage").text(message);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to maintain a reference to the last status received:

```
var Poller = {

    //// monitorStatus function

    lastStatus: "Initialized", // just needs to something other than one of the actual statuses

    updateDivCounter: function(status, message)
    {
        if (status === this.lastStatus) {
             return;   // don't do anything if the statuses match
        }

        this.lastStatus = status;

        //Increment the notificationCount DIV Tag
        $(".notificationCount").text( function (i,current) { return +current+1;} ) ;

        //Print the notification in notificationMessage Div tag
        $(".notificationMessage").text(message);
    }

}
```

Comment: That's awesome.. :) Thanks. My brain is too fried today to have missed this. :)